# Gmaps API - Adding event listener on loop always points to the last marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Heloo there.

I have an array of markers.

I'm looping thourgh then, and adding a click event for each one:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){ 
   //Logic using position goes here
}
```

The problem is no matter which one I click the position is always from the last marker added.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're adding the listener in the loop right ?

Comment: Right. I'm also creating the markers themselves in the loop. The array contains the information only.

Comment: You want to open a different infowindow for each marker or something else ?

Comment: There's a button on the infoWindow that calls a function that will use the position for some processing...

Comment: I think you are being affected by closures: an example in case you want to pursue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: and I took away the down vote...This is a good problem (and it gets the best of us in the google maps implementation world). Especially when we have to customize code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `position` is just a variable that you are updating each time through the loop then the event handler functions you are creating will all share this same variable and use its current value.

See the section "Creating closures in loops: A common mistake" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures for an explanation.